# How to retrieve a login form written in simple html file when clicked on the login button using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

After running the index.html file when we click on login button, the form needs to be displayed for which I have created a login.html file, now how do I link this file in flask? I have put all the html files in the templates folder. Obviously the info added by the user needs to be entered into the MySQL workbench database.

Comment: Did you [read the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you'd like to have users directed from the index.html page to the login.html page. If so, you could simply add a link to the login page URL within the index page and have Flask handle the connection via a route.

A simple example would be to insert something like the following into your views.py/routes.py file, or your main app file if you are doing a very simple application (in which case you can leave out the import, obviously):

```
from app import app
@app.route('/path/to/login')
def login()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login')
```

where `app` is your Flask application object and `/path/to/login` is a relative URL appended to your main domain URI.

To make things a bit more maintainable and reusable, you might reference the link to the login page in index.html by using the Jinja2 template engine to automatically populate your anchor tag's href with the desired URL path:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
```

This should get you from index.html to the login.html page with the form.

For more info, [check the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/views/).